# UITableView scroll to selected cell after navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table View that fetching remote data from backend which is all working fine, what i'm trying to accomplish is when user click on any cell to navigate to other ViewController (details controller) and when press the back button the table view should scroll to the selected cell and not to go back to top i'v tried `tableView.scrollToRow` as shown below but its not working? i know that i'm calling `tableView.reloadData()` in my loading data function other wise it won't load

```
class feeds: UITableViewController {
    var data = [AnyObject]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        LoadData()
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return data.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

       // configur tabl cell

        return cell
    }

    func LoadData(){

    // Fetch Feeds to dataArray 
        // Reload UITable View
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        let celloffset = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "celloffset")
        if celloffset != 0{
        let index = IndexPath(item: celloffset, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: false)
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath.row, forKey: "celloffset")

        // Navigate to Details VC
    }

}
```

Any help or ideas will be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

When you are coming back to initial view controller, then you don't need to fetch data again. Simply use `ViewWillAppear` method. Get the `celloffset` and scroll table view.

```
let celloffset = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "celloffset")
if celloffset != 0{
let index = IndexPath(item: celloffset, section: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: false)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but could explain more how not to load the data again when back to the table view ? i'm storing the data in an array  and when get back to tableview this array will be recreated as will so i have to reload the data again

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is only called once upon view controller initialization, not when popping view controllers on navigation stack. Call `LoadData()`
in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    LoadData()
}
```

Comment: thanks  for your reply, but i'm getting below error 
`'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (7) beyond bounds (5) for section (0).'`

Comment: You are trying to scroll to a row that doesn't exists.

Comment: I know what its mean, my array has 25 rows after loading i selected cell no 7 when press back button the error is occurred 
i think its because the data is reloading !

Comment: if i remove it the table view will dispaly nothing